# Material Icons not showing in Browser

Tags: html, angular, button, angular-material, resolve

I want to implement a refresh button.

I have added this to my index.html:

`<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">`

I placed the button in another html file:

`<button class="refreshButton" mat-icon-button> <mat-icon>home</mat-icon> </button>`

Why can't my browser still not resolve the icon?

I have also added the module to my app.module.ts:
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon'
`@NgModule({ imports: [ MatIconModule, ]}`

Do I need this anyway?

Comment: Try adding it through npm, look at this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-icon-rjjvma?file=app%2Fapp.component.html,app%2Fapp.component.ts,index.html,app%2Fapp.module.ts) then you don't need the import through the link in your index.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, install `material-icons` using:

```
npm install material-icons --save
```

secondly, import in `style.css`:

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons");
```